# Hidden file on internal storage

Tags: internal-storage

I really like to delete some spaces on my internal storage, i checked all the folders on internal, mostly it was 4 GB only, my question is how would i find the remaining 6gb space because my internal storage have a total of 10gb only regardless of 5 gb space for system.

I didnt know how to find it, please do help me to solve this problem.

thanks.

Comment: What device and Android version? Is the device rooted? What did you use to check? Have you already consulted our [internal-storage tag-wiki](/tags/internal-storage/info) and [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info)?

Comment: You should know that the operating system itself may take up to 5Gb of disk space, depending on the Android version your phone is running.

Comment: My internal storage is 16GB, and i am using Marshmallow OS, as far as i know the 6GB will deducted because it was dedicated to the system, so the remaining 10GB will declared as my internal storage.

Comment: i already checked all the folders on my internal storage but i was just found that 6 GB was missing. thanks for those you will answer. ^_^